# Как сохранить массив с данными при перезагрузке Pjax yii2

Tags: javascript, yii2

у меня есть gridView в нем я использую yii\grid\CheckboxColumn, все работает отлично кроме одного момента, виджет находится внутри PJAX, и при пагинации чекбоксы на других странцах сбрасываются. Подскажите как лучше решить эту проблему. Я пока сохраняю массив в localstorage но не думаю что это правильный путь.

```
Pjax::begin(['id' => 'pjax-grid-campaign',
                            'enablePushState' => false,
                            'enableReplaceState' => true,
                            'timeout' => false,
                            ]);
                        echo '<div class="table-block">';

                            echo GridView::widget([
                                'id' => 'grid',
                                'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                                'tableOptions' => ['class' => 'campaign-table table-defolt-theme large-only', 'id' => 'card-table'],
                                'layout' => '{items}',
                                'summary' => false,
                                'columns' => [
                                    [
                                        'class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn',
                                        'contentOptions'=>[],
                                        'checkboxOptions' => function ($model, $key, $index, $column) {
                                            return ['value' => $model->id];
                                        },
                                    ],
```

это view

```
$this->registerJs('
                                $("document").ready(function () {
                                    let checkbox = $("input[type=checkbox]");
                                    let keys;
                                    checkbox.change(function () {
                                        let btn = $("#mass-price-change");
                                        keys = $("#grid").yiiGridView("getSelectedRows");
                                        console.log(keys);
                                        let count = 0;
                                        for (let i=0; i<=checkbox.length-1; i++) {
                                            if (checkbox.eq(i).is(":checked")) {
                                                count++;
                                            }
                                        }

                                        if (count) {
                                            btn.prop("disabled", false);
                                            btn.css("background", "#fda51b");
                                            btn.css("color", "black");
                                        } else {
                                            btn.prop("disabled", true);
                                            btn.css("background", "#6687b3");
                                            btn.css("color", "white");
                                        };
                                    });
                                });

                                $(".price-change-campaign").click(function (e) {
                                    e.preventDefault();
                                    let keys = $("#grid").yiiGridView("getSelectedRows");
                                    $.ajax({
                                        url: "/rk/campaign/mass-change-price",
                                        type: "GET",
                                        data: {campaign_ids: keys},
                                        success: function (data) {
                                            $(document).off("submit", "#pjax-mass-price-change-modal form[data-pjax]");
                                            $("#add-price-change-modal .modal-body").html(data);
                                            $(".select-2").select2({theme: "default dark-theme", width: "100%"});
                                        }
                                    });
                                });', View::POS_LOAD);
```

это js

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте форму. В нее `hidden`-поле. Каждому элементу столбца `checkBoxColumn` дайте `id`. На событие `pjax:beforeSend` навесьте свою функцию. В ней пробегите по столбцу `checkBoxColumn` и для каждого его элемента сохраните в скрытое поле список всех `id` и `checked` или нет в формате `json` - например `[{"id": "ClientPrice1", "checked": true}, {"id": "ClientPrice2", "checked": false}]`. Если элемент уже есть - обновите его значение, если нет - добавьте. На событие `pjax:complete` навесьте еще одну функцию. В ней уже делайте обратное действие - получите из `json` массив, пробегитесь по нему и по столбцу `checkboxColumn` найдете совпадение по `id` - смотрите на значение `checked` в `json` и выставляете соответствующее состояние `checkbox`-а.